# You tube on Rails - regular expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I am trying to integrate you tube with my rails 4 app.

I am following this tutorial: http://www.sitepoint.com/youtube-rails/

I have added this validation on my video model:

```
YT_LINK_FORMAT = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/i

validates :link, presence: true, format: YT_LINK_FORMAT
```

I get this error when I try it:

```
The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $), which may present a security risk. Did you mean to use \A and \z, or forgot to add the :multiline => true option?
```

Is there a safe way of using this concept?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, use `\A` and `\z`, so to avoid potential javascript exploits.

Comment: so does it mean replace each '^' with \A and each '$' with \z? There are no '$' in the current expression, so I just need to switch '^' for '\A'?

Comment: or does it mean that I should put \A at the beginning of the expression and \z at the end of it and leave all the ^ as they are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others who might be trying to understand regex, I found this example as a replacement. The \A \z go in the expression, rather than replacing uses of ^ or $, so in my case - it's: /\A.*(youtu.be/|v/|u/\w/|embed/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*\z/i